# comparator isn't behaving as it should

Tags: comparator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frwgbh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output is always outputting 5V, and I have no idea why. I have checked the inputs to the comp, I even switch them around its never hits 0 volts. Yes I am double checking that input from the OPA350 is greater than the Vrf.

Comment: is the ground pin connected?

Comment: Yeah, weirdest thing, Pin 4 grounded VSS

Comment: What did you do with the CSn pin of the MCP6548?

Comment: Needing to know details like this is why you should post a **complete** schematic of your circuit, not just the parts you think might be important.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didnt know that was important I left it floating (Unconnected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems most likely that you have either tied the \$\rm\overline{CS}\$ input high, or you left it unconnected and it randomly drifted high due to static charge or capacitive coupling to nearby objects.

With \$\rm\overline{CS}\$ high, the output goes into a high-impedance state as described on p. 16 of the datasheet, which allows R3 to pull the output high.

**Edit**

In comments you now confirmed you left it unconnected.

As a general rule, you should never leave CMOS inputs floating, as this can produce unpredictable circuit behavior (even oscillation and circuit self-destruction in certain worst case scenarios). If a chip has an internal pull-up or pull-down allowing a logic input to be left unconnected, it will nearly always be mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: Wow, amazing. It works now. Thank you so much. (I grounded the CS pin)